# Do Spark SQL databases and managed tables persist?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and working my way through the O'Reilly book, so hopefully my question makes sense.

One of the exercises is to create a Spark application that does the following:

```
# Create a new DB
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE learn_spark_db")
spark.sql("USE learn_spark_db")

# Import data and write to a managed table
flights_df = spark.read.csv(csv_file, schema=schema)
flights_df.write.saveAsTable("managed_flights_tbl")
```

If I run this once it works fine but if I run it again I get an error:

```
Can not create the managed table('`managed_flights_tbl`'). The associated location('file:/C:/Users/.../spark-warehouse/learn_spark_db.db/managed_flights_tbl') already exists.;
```

I am trying to understand this behaviour. It looks like the database and managed table persist after the application has finished running. However, if I write a separate application that tries to access the managed table I get a 'table does not exist' error.

When writing an application is it good practice to drop tables and databases once you are done with them to keep everything 'clean'?

Is there any way I can clean up the external table 'learn_spark_db.managed_flights_tbl' or have I lost access to it now the application has finished running?

Am I just totally missing something...?

Comment: What is the separate application?

Answer (score 1):

I Faced the same problem when I created a python file and execute it from "spark-submit".

the problem was in SparkSession, you should to add enableHiveSupport()

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .appName('SamplePySparkDev')\
    .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using at least the Spark default catalog and as such the data is persisted as you will have `spark.sql.catalogImplementation` set to "hive".

We do not know how you are accessing the table in a different application. Using Hive without saving as Hive table in Spark can be problematic.